# download file and send message as response in Postman

Tags: express, postman

Is it possible to download a file and send a success message via `Postman` at the same time?

This is my code:

```
res.download(file);
res.status(200).json({ 'result': 'file downloaded!' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint, according to express doc: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download , `res.download` allows callback, so have you tried to do something there?

```
res.download('/report-12345.pdf', 'report.pdf', function (err) {
  if (err) {
    // Handle error, but keep in mind the response may be partially-sent
    // so check res.headersSent
  } else {
    // decrement a download credit, etc.
  }
})
```